# After one has made many grid based puzzles how does one make then into a PDF ready for printing

Tags: puzzle

Here is a part image of my finished book;

[image]

After one has generated many grid based puzzles like sudoku, kakuro or even plain crosswords and now one has to print them in a book. How does one make a pdf (book file) from them automatically. To explain the question better.

The puzzles are already made into single files stored in the 1..4.6..9 format. There are nine lines in every file. So each file is a complete sudoku puzzle. Now I want to print a book from them. Let us say to keep things simple one puzzle to a page and nothing else on the page. So it would need a grid box as well. The first one I could make as a template in word. How do I make the others without putting in the different numbers every time individually. I have kept this as simple as possible.

This type of question concerns anyone making books of 'puzzles' (and many others) where each page is the same just the numbers or words different. I have been sent to this site by two others 'puzzle' sites on here. It is inappropriate please direct me further.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you describe your problem in more detail? How have you generated these puzzles? Is there some code piece for each puzzle, do you have the PDFs, etc.

Comment: @Torbjørn T Thank you. I asked this question elsewhere and was told it belongs here. I do have my own answer but there may be better ones. Please see my profile here but still unfinished. I have generated these puzzles using my own program. They are now in 'computer' form. Meaning a1=1 a2=2 etc. They now have to be put into 'paper' form meaning a printable PDF book. How does one do this without having to typeset each one singularly.

Comment: Your question is very vague, because I can answer: Use [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages), which may be sufficient. Or I could say: Use some tools from the [PDF Toolkit](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)... but then again, it *seems* like you don't actually have these puzzles set on a page yet. I think it would be better if you break your question into smaller components, the first of which is: "I have *this* input and I want the output to look like *that* using LaTeX. How can I do that?"

Comment: @Werner You miss the main thrust of my question. I have already provided part of my own answer which I use. The question is how to do it automatically not how to do it. Meaning doing only one and the others get done automatically.

Comment: @alanross: Your question needs some clear direction for it to be answered. As of now, it's fully unclear to me without an example of your input, perhaps some LaTeX code, or just an image of what you're after...

Comment: I'm using `logicpuzzle.sty` + `qqwing` and a bash script to automaticly creating a Sudoke magazine, see: http://logicpuzzle.square7.de/lpsmag and http://logicpuzzle.square7.de/texdoku! Up to now it is really unclear want you really want to do! Create puzzles or just composing existing puzzle images on a page?

Comment: @Werner You can see an image here http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Automated_Sudoku.html?id=HGP17wkz-LEC&redir_esc=y  or here http://www.amazon.co.uk/250-Kakuro-Puzzles-Alan-Ross/dp/190446825X Some sites have a copy of the first few pages.

Comment: @Josef composing existing puzzles but not yet on an image on a page only in computer format onto a page automatically. Meaning not doing each one separately.

Comment: http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HGP17wkz-LEC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false look at page eight for an example of four to a page plus a step by step guide.

Comment: @alanross What do you mean with computer format? Can you export to a standard format like `81` or `Simple Sudoku`? I've written a `bash` script `createlpsudoku`, which transform Sudoku formats into `lpsudoku` environments that can be used in a LaTeX document. See: http://logicpuzzle.square7.de/createlpsudoku and http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/logicpuzzle

Comment: @Josef Computer format let us say is ...4..6.87 on each line for all nine lines. The 'dot' being the empty cell. Now one has to put it into a grid box onto a page plus another three puzzles and their answers in my step by step guide. One can do it singly like I do the first one but how after that can it be done automatically using a batch file. The link I provided has a good picture of it.

Comment: @alanross: This question will soon be closed since it remains unclear. Don't post links to external sites that may be dead down the road. Include practical examples in your original post that will remain here forever more. You can do the same with images. See [How can I upload an image to be included in a question or answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2136/5764)

Comment: @Werner I have included a picture in the question. There are really four to a page but I cant get them all in. It should be clear now.

Comment: @alanross 'I shall give now part of my answer. If one wants to put 4 or two puzzles on a page, one used word to do this....' Why the mystery? It is your question. Why only reveal part of any answer you have. It is not even clear to me that you want to use LaTeX since your part answer mentions using Word. And it is not at all clear since you have not provided any of the information requested. (I don't see any image but you certainly have not given us sample input or code.)

Comment: @cfr I have put an image and I have explained my question as best as I can.

Comment: Seems to be a really stupid spammer. Just see his user page http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/53810/alan-ross Full of spam!

Comment: @josef calling me stupid because I can do 'black magic' what you cant will not make you any the wiser. Instead of asking me how I do it (nicely of course) you will remain ignorant of the 'black magic'.

Comment: @Josef what you can do for me is to word the question in a format you believe is suitable. I have tried my best but to no avail. I believe you at last understand the question so I would be grateful if you would do this for me.

Comment: With regard to Su Doku, see if the `printsudoku` package from the `sudoku` bundle does most of what you're after. Having a file `puzzle.sud` containing nine lines in the format you describe, try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{printsudoku}
\cluefont{\normalsize}
\cellsize{1.5\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\sudoku{puzzle.sud}\hfill\sudoku{puzzle.sud}
\par
\bigskip
\sudoku{puzzle.sud}\hfill\sudoku{puzzle.sud}
\end{center}
\end{document}`, and see if that does anything like what you're after.

Comment: @Torbjørn T thank you. I can see that I dont belong here. Over twenty comments and still no one understands what I am after. I give up. My profile has my email if anyone does understand and is interested how I do it.

Comment: @alanross I'm sorry that you think so, my intention was not to chase you away. I do realise my comment does not solve the automation, it was thought merely as a step along the way. I.e., is the representation on the page OK? However, there *are* elements to your question that are unclear, IMO. Some may be improved in comments, but people shouldn't have to read all the comments to get all the information. If for example you have one puzzle per file called `puzzle1.txt`, `puzzle2.txt` etc., your question could read something like: (ctd.)

Comment: '*I have N files called `puzzleI.txt`, which looks like <insert complete example of file>, each representing a sudokupuzzle. How can I display them, four to a page, without inputting each one separately, in this LaTeX document. <insert minimal LaTeX document if you have one>.*' Of course, if you want the same for Kakuro, you will have to give an example of the input (how the data is organized) and the output (an image). If the output given by the code in my previous comment is OK, you can use that as a starting point.

Comment: @Torbjørn T Thank you for your continued interest. As the one answer has stated it can only be done through black magic. I dont know latex. But if I have to get a job done I would learn. I have done my best to explain my 'job'. I was told by two other sites to come to this site because they thought it could be done by latex. I should mention again that anyone doing what I am doing that is making puzzles would be asking the same question. Which is how to typeset automatically. And that means almost any kind of puzzle.

Comment: @Torbjørn T  I have my own developed methods not using latex but I am always willing to learn new ones and share mine. I do not follow the herd as my books prove, they are unique, no other books are similar. I still dont think you have fully understood my question. It is not about how many to display on a page. It is about making one template (whatever you put on the page) and then managing to do many others with changing the numbers and  letters which make ita different puzzle,automatically. Most puzzles work this way and are typeset individually. My question is how to do it 'collectively'.

Comment: @jon please see the above. I find it very puzzling that something as important as my question which relates to many, many other types of puzzles and other things where the same 'page' is used only the words and numbers change have  not found an outlet where this can be discussed and ideas exchanged.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm being obtuse, but I still don't grasp exactly what you're after, and I don't think you fully understood me either. Four to a page was an example, you could replace it with whatever pattern you want. You have said that the puzzles are already made, and stored in the format you mentioned ( e.g `1..4.6..9` for a row), and that what you need is way of typesetting all of these puzzles. So if you can edit your question and give a complete example of such a puzzle, clearly stating how you want all of them laid out, then the question may be reopened and a better answer appear.

Comment: Torbjørn T Correct the puzzles are already made into single file stored in the 1..4.6..9 format. There are nine lines in every file. So each file is a complete sudoku puzzle. Now I want to print a book from them. Let us say to keep things simple one puzzle to a page and nothing else on the page. So it would need a grid box as well. The first one I make as a template in word. How do I make the others without putting in the different numbers every time individually. I have kept this as simple as possible.

Comment: If you want to use Word you're on the wrong site, Superuser is likely better. If you want to use LaTeX, install TeX Live or MacTeX (depending on platform), open up TeXworks, paste the code I wrote before (starting with `\documentclass`), save the file as `something.tex`, place one of those puzzle files in the same folder and rename it to `puzzle.sud` (or change the code), then click the green arrow on the toolbar in TeXworks. A PDF should open.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/762651/how-does-one-make-many-word-programs-from-a-template have done. Thanks.

Comment: @Josef Indeed; see also his user page on Puzzling (which previously also had 6 spam answers).

Comment: @Alanross What I think is needed here, after looking over the comments, is an example in the question of (1) the input format you have (I guess a text file) and (2) the output such a file should produce. If we know the exact format then it all sounds doable using TeX but we do need to know the exact details of the format required.

Comment: @Joseph Wright The exact details are given here. The input is similar to one in the answer and the output is in the question. I must again reiterate that this is not just for sudoku and kakuro but for many other problems.I have my own way of doing it using ms-word and I am already giving up that there is another way as the one answer has already said.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume you have a puzzle in `Simple Sudoku` format like

```
test.ss
1..|...|7..
.2.|...|5..
6..|38.|...
-----------
.78|...|...
...|6.9|...
...|...|14.
-----------
...|.25|..9
..3|...|.6.
..4|...|..2
```

Then `createlpsudoku -sw -i test.ss -o test.tex` will create a `test.tex` with a `lpsudoku` environment, which you can use in a LaTeX document:

```
\begin{lpsudoku}
  \setrow{9}{1,{},{},{},{},{},7,{},{}}
  \setrow{8}{{},2,{},{},{},{},5,{},{}}
  \setrow{7}{6,{},{},3,8,{},{},{},{}}
  \setrow{6}{{},7,8,{},{},{},{},{},{}}
  \setrow{5}{{},{},{},6,{},9,{},{},{}}
  \setrow{4}{{},{},{},{},{},{},1,4,{}}
  \setrow{3}{{},{},{},{},2,5,{},{},9}
  \setrow{2}{{},{},3,{},{},{},{},6,{}}
  \setrow{1}{{},{},4,{},{},{},{},{},2}
\end{lpsudoku}
```

This will work for standard Sudoku layout. But there is no standard format for Kakuro. You will have to develop something on your own or use images that you create anyhow. There's no black magic that turns puzzles in ***your*** format into a pdf ready for printing!

Comment: sorry to disappoint you but there is and I have proved it! I wouldnt call it black magic though. I think I will have to wait to tell you till the question is fully understood. I am still not sure what is troubling everybody. It sounds so simple to me.

Comment: @alanross First, you say you don't want to compose images and give a format like `123456789`. Then you have "proved it" and you magicly have images. Okay, use them! Are you just trolling? With this confusing question style nobody can help you!

Comment: I shall explain again. I do want to compose images direct to the printed page. But at present I have the format 123456789 Now I want to make this format into a PDf ready typeset for printing. Just because you cant do it doesnt mean no one else can.

Comment: I agree there is a 'trick' to it. But the main thing it works and has done for all my books.

Comment: Please tell me how I can explain it better. Two people have upvoted it so they seem to understand it and I am sure they want to know the answer. It is not fair to withhold it from them. They may need it to print their books.

Comment: @alanross I assume you are trolling. Now you claim to already have an answer which other people are mysteriously preventing you from sharing with other people. In that case, I have no idea why you asked the question - at least, I certainly have no idea why you did not immediately answer that question. It is fine to post a question in order to provide an answer you think will be useful to others but it is only useful to others if (1) they can understand the question and (2) you do give the answer. Again, why the mystery?

Comment: @alanross If it worked for all your books, why the hell you don't just use what worked so far? Are you just spammimg? Two out of three 5-star reviews of your Kakuro book seem to be written by yourself. Okay, i got the message! Score adjusted EOT

Comment: @josef I unlike you are willing to share my knowledge or what you call black magic and am also willing to learn. That is why I am here. If this site is not meant for people like me only like you please say so.

Comment: @cfr I also dont understand the mystery of the question. Look how many comments it has taken to explain it and it still doesnt seem to register. The people on here seem to be too clever to understand simple things.

Comment: @alanross -- If you have an answer, then post it.  People will then be able to suggest an improved answer.  (However, and I mean no offence by this, I'm still not convinced you know what TeX or LaTeX or ConTeXt is, so I doubt your answer or question is appropriate for this site.  This is not a site that generically answers questions about creating PDFs or books.)

Comment: @jon I am sure you are right. Can you please suggest me a site where I would be more welcome. I am already on three sites here. Each one directing me to another and non understanding the simple question.

Comment: @alanross: Do you know TeX or LaTeX?

Comment: I wish I knew a good site.  Maybe a site devoted to the software you currently use for your own not-quite-automatic solution.  I unfortunately know nothing about the creation of any sort of puzzles.  Josef's answer already got my vote, but it is a LaTeX solution, which I don't think you want to use..?